# CKEditor Header Styles - h1 is applied to entire paragraph block and not just the selected text

Tags: html, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in OpenCart 1.4.9.3.  My problem is with the paragraph tags it automatically add and how it handles applying header tags.  Say I have this text:

Example text here

This is some example text.

CKEditor has them both in the same paragraph block even though they're on different lines.  I highlight Example text here and select h1.  It makes both lines h1 instead of just my selected line.

How can I fix this?  I imported over 1000 products so I can't very well go through and replace every p with a br, especially since in any new product, the editor will add p tags anyway.  I am aware I can add the header styles in Source, but my coworkers can not handle html.  They need to be able to highlight a line and change it to h1 or h2 without hassle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it works if there's a br to make a linefeed, but not when there's a paragraph?
As I've figured, the h1 would apply to the whole paragraph, ie change the p to h1.

Try the same in your Word Processor, with linefeed (ctrl+enter) or new paragraph (enter).